# SSRS Date parameter ranges

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, reporting-services, parameters

I have a new requirement to design report using date range parameters for Start and End dates in my report.

I am using this queries in my report:

Main Dataset:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, StartDate, TargetDate, Col3
FROM Table
WHERE (StartDate BETWEEN @StartDateFrom AND @StartDateTo)
    AND (TargetDate BETWEEN @TargetDateFrom AND @TargetDateTo)
```

Dataset 1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Col1
FROM  Table
```

Dataset 2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Col2
FROM Table
WHERE (Col1IN (@Param1))
ORDER BY Col2
```

Dataset 3:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM  Table
WHERE (Col1 IN (@Param1)) 
    AND (Col2 IN (@Param2))
GROUP BY Col1, Col2, Col3
```

While running the report I get an error: TargetDate parameter is missing value.

Can someone help?

Comment: `Target_Date <> TargetDate` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where you are "DECLARE"ing your variables @TargetDateTo and @TargetDateFrom?  You may want to check your query again as SSRS may not be picking up all your variables.